# Work energy theorem explanation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work

So there is this problem in my head, it may seem very simple, but I need an answer. The problem is, we have some  object, and we apply a force by our hands with a constant speed from a position (1) to (2). And there is a theorem which says that the work done to displace an object from pos.(1) to (2) is the difference of kinetic energies of the second minus the first. But the thing is " we're moving it at a constant speed" which means by the equation the work becomes zero, but its not a logical answer since there has been a displacement..

Comment: ...why does it matter that there's displacement *when there is no force*?

Comment: I edit the question, I meant by moving it, applying a force...

Comment: we move it with a constant speed from a position (1) to (2)....., so how it was moved ...i just wonder.

Comment: If you apply a force the object doesn't move at constant speed. Or, well, if you apply a force such that the object moves at constant speed, then yes, no work is done because the force then is orthogonal to the displacement.

Comment: Oh okay now I understand, but what if the time of the process is 20 sec, and I began analysing the process at time =3 sec to time equal 18 sec, so there is no change in the velocity and there is the force done by my hand :)

Comment: It upsets when someone unvotes my question, I know my questions are really simple, but its okay.. Not only intelligent people want to benefit, but also normal people like me

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240871/2451

Comment: @Za Kh: during the period when no force is applied (constant velocity) the Law of Inertia keeps it moving - assuming a no frictional losses environment.  The general work-energy theorem does not require constant force; but then it requires calculus to frame the analysis.

Comment: But there is an applied force because if I removed my hand and stopped pushing it, it would stop moving

Comment: @ZaKh: If it stops when you remove your hand, then there are other forces at working against the motion; presumably friction.  The work-energy theorem does not account for dissipative forces like friction; the energy is lost to the mechanical system.

Comment: The formula is not $$W= \Delta K$$ but $$W_{total} = \Delta K$$ So remember to find *all* forces and sum the work they are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Considering to your question and comments below it, I think that you have been confused about some assumptions. For example, when we assume that there is no friction, you should be able to imagine a situation that there is no friction in that. You shouldn’t imagine real life for that assumption, because in your common daily life, you cannot find a perfect friction-less experience.

> We have some object, and we apply a force by our hands with a **constant speed**

If we apply a force, and **if this force is the only force** that is exerted to the object (try to imagine this situation); then the object won’t move with a constant speed. Because $a=\large{\frac Fm}\neq 0$.

If we apply a force and the object moves with a constant speed; then our force isn’t the only force that is exerted to the object. For example, it may that there is a gravitational force that makes the net force becomes zero.

> We're moving it at a constant speed which means by the equation the **work** becomes zero

What is the work in work energy theorem? That work is work done by **all** external forces acting on the object. As I mentioned above, if you are exerting a force on an object and it is moving with a constant speed, your force isn’t the only force acting on the object. According to the work energy theorem work done by all external forces is equal to zero. I.e. work done by you + work done by other forces (for example weight force)=$0$. Your work isn’t zero. **Net** work done on the object is zero ($W_{\textrm{net}}=\Sigma W$)

Comment: Oops thank you a lot for explaining , it was a misunderstanding in the principles.. :/

Answer (score 0):

actually you got it wrong work energy theorem states that the net work done is equal to change in k.e here you have to concentrate on the word net .. because net work done work done  by you and work done by frictional force is zero......